# Error starting web application passenger nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

[image: web page[![][1]]

When loading a simple rails app, I get an html page stating. web application error. From the log files i find this.

```
Could not spawn process for application /var/www/html/railapp: The application encountered the following error: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Error ID: c24e0564
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-Wc9XgI.html

The webapp is the simple "yay! I'm on rails" with no modifications.

Rails 5.2.2 Ruby 2.5.5 I followed the guide at phusion and nginx started ok. The tests say. "everything ok" I looked at questions for stack too deep and passenger startup issues, But I didn't see anything particular to this issue and passenger. I have tried the ruby path suggested by rvm and also by using "which ruby' at the command line, but still the same error.

Comment: SystemStackError is a very generic error which occurs if you have some sort of circular logic. Thus its really pointless to google it as it tells you almost nothing about the cause. You need to take a deeper look at the logs to try to figure out what is actually going wrong.

Comment: It's not in my logic because the app is simply the rails generic app when you type rails new. There is another thread where a ruby prior to mine was causing a SystemStack error due to  a bug. Supposedly that was fixed. Here's what I'm getting in 2.6.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




















gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/SystemStackError.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. I started with googling the error message and landed here.
[Getting an stack level too deep when testing on 2.4]

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25125
I downgraded  Rails 5.2.2 to Rails 4.2.10 and Ruby 2.6.1 to ruby 2.4.2p198

Then the error messages started reflecting sqlite3 issues, so i  reinstalled sqlite3 to 1.3.13

The 'Welcome to Rails' page is now working and I can finally start on my project. I just wnt to get going on a simple blog, so downgrading is not an issue for me.

edit to add: It's now working on rails v 5.22 and ruby -v 2.43 serving at /var/www/html/railsapp